# W3 validation error

Tags: html, validation

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title> ARPIT - Accounting & Reconciliation Portal of Indirect Taxes </title>

    <!-- Fonts -->

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    @*<link href="~/Content/theme/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />*@
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="~/Content/theme/assets/admin/css/custom_website.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="~/Content/theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="~/Content/theme/assets/global/plugins/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/theme/assets/global/plugins/respond.min.js"></script>

    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body id="content">
    <div class="page-wrap ">
        <header id="header" style="min-height: 163px;">
            <div class="header-body" style="top: 0px;">
                <div class="header-top">
                    <div class=" container-xl container">
                        <div class="top-responsive-menu">
                            <div class="top-menu-area">
                                <ul class=" nav navbar-nav top-menu-4">
                                    <li class="login">
                                        <a href="@Url.Action("LoginLanguageChange", "HomePage", null)" title="Log In" id="lblLogin"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> @CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resLoginMenu </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="top-menu-area ">
                                <a href="#" class="top-menu-3"> @CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resColorThemeMenu <i class="fa fa-caret-down top -menu-3"></i></a>
                                <ul class=" nav navbar-nav top-menu menu-3  ">
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                                            <img src="~/Images/multicolor.png" style="width:25px" title="Color Theme" alt="Color Theme">
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu multicolors-name">
                                            <li><a href="#">@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resGreenThemeMenu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resBlueThemeMenu</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="menu-3-2" title="White Theme">@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resWhiteThemeMenu</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="menu-3-3" title="Black Theme">@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resBlackThemeMenu</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="top-menu-area">
                                <ul class=" nav navbar-nav top-menu-2 ">
                                    <li class="language menu-2" title="हिन्दी"><a href="#" id="btnHindiEnglish">@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resLanguageMenu</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>



                            <div class="top-menu-area">
                                <a href="#" class="top-menu-name-1" style=""> @CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resZoomMenu <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                                <ul class=" nav navbar-nav top-menu menu-1 top-menu-1">
                                    <li><a href="#" class="zoom" title="Increase Font Size" onclick=increaseFont() style="padding:6px 14px 6px 0px;">@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resIncreaseFontMenu </a></li>
                                    <li><a class="zoom" href="#" title="Reset Font Size" style="padding: 6px 14px 6px 3px;" onclick=resetFont()>@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resResetFontMenu</a></li>
                                    <li style="margin-right:20px"><a class="zoom " href="#" title="Decrease Font Size" onclick=decreaseFont() style=" padding: 6px 14px 6px 3px;"> @CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resDecreaseFontMenu </a></li>
                                </ul>

                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- <p class="welcome-msg">DEFAULT WELCOME MSG!</p> -->
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="header-container container container-xl">
                    <div class="header-row">
                        <div class="header-column">
                            <div class="header-logo">
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "HomePage", null)">
                                    <img alt="ARPIT" class="logo" src="~/images/arpit_logo.png" title="Accounting & Reconciliation Portal of Indirect Taxes">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="header-column">
                            <div class="header-logo govt-authorities-name">
                                <img alt="CCA & CBEC" title="CCA & CBIC" height="76" src="~/Images/govt-authorities.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed -top header-container header-nav" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container container-xl responsive-padding-menu">
                        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills responsive-nav navigation">
                                <li class="menuSelect" id="Index">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "HomePage", null)" title="Home">
                                        @CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CAS_Resource.Home
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="dropdown-submenu menuSelec t" id="AboutUs">
                                    <a href="#" title="About Us" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        @CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CAS_Resource.AboutUs <b class="caret"></b>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="about-dropdown-menu dropdown-menu ">
                                        <li id="Overview"><a href="@Url.Action("Overview", "StaticPage", null)" title="Overview">@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resOverviewMenu </a></li>
                                        <li id="OrganisationChart"><a href="@Url.Action("OrganisationChart", "StaticPage", null)" title="Organisation Chart">@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resOrganisationChartMenu</a></li>
                                        <li id="OrganisationFunctions"><a href="@Url.Action("OrganisationFunctions", "StaticPage", null)" title="Organisation Functions">@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resAboutUsOrganisationFunctionMenu</a></li>
                                        <li id="DirectoryofOfficers"><a href="@Url.Action("DirectoryofOfficers", "StaticPage", null)" title="Directory of officers">@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resAboutUsDirectoryofOfficersMenu</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menuSelect" id="Administration">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Administration", "StaticPage", null)" title="Administration">
                                        @CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resAdministrationMenu
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menuSelect" id="PAO">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("PAO", "StaticPage", null)" title="PAO">
                                        @CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resPAOMenu
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menuSelect" id="DDODirectory">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("DDODirectory", "StaticPage", null)" title="DDO Directory">
                                        @CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resDDODirectoryMenu
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menuSelect" id="ListofAuthorisedBanks">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("ListofAuthorisedBanks", "StaticPage", null)" title="List of Authorised Banks">
                                        @CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resListofAuthorisedBanksMenu
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menuSelect" id="Publication">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Publication", "StaticPage", null)" title="Publication">
                                        @CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resPublicationMenu
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menuSelect" id="Tender">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Tender", "StaticPage", null)" title="Tender">
                                        @CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resTenderMenu
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menuSelect" id="ContactUs">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("ContactUs", "StaticPage", null)" title="Contact Us">
                                        @CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resContactUsMenu
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.container -->
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        @RenderBody()

    </div>
    <footer id="footer">
        <div class="footer-link">
            <div class="container container-xl">
                <div class="bottomNav">
                    <nav>
                        <ul class=" bottomnavControls social-icons">
                            <li class="footer-image"><a href="@Url.Action("Sitemap", "StaticPage", null)" title="Sitemap"><i class="fa fa-sitemap footer-icon"></i>@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resSitemapMenu </a> </li>
                            <li class="footer-image"><a href="@Url.Action("Feedback", "StaticPage", null)" title="Feedback"><i class="fa fa-comments footer-icon"></i>@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resFeedbackMenu  </a></li>

                            <li class="footer-image"><a href="@Url.Action("FAQ", "StaticPage", null)" title="FAQ"><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o footer-icon"></i>@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resFAQMenu </a></li>

                            <li class="footer-image"><a href="@Url.Action("RTI", "StaticPage", null)" title="RTI"><i class="fa fa-users footer-icon"></i> @CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resRTIMenu </a></li>

                            <li class="footer-image"><a href="@Url.Action("Disclaimer", "StaticPage", null)" title="Disclaimer"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle footer-icon "></i>@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resDisclaimerMenu </a></li>
                            <li class="footer-image"><a href="@Url.Action("TermsofUse", "StaticPage", null)" title="Terms of Use"><i class="fa fa-pencil footer-icon"></i>@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resTermsofUseMenu  </a></li>
                            <li class="footer-image"><a href="@Url.Action("AccessibilityStatement", "StaticPage", null)" title="Accessibility Statement"><i class="fa fa-wheelchair footer-icon "></i>@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resAccessibilityStatementMenu  </a></li>
                            <li class="footer-image"><a href="@Url.Action("WebsitePolicies", "StaticPage", null)" title="Website Policies"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o footer-icon"></i>@CGA.CPSMS.BusinessModels.ResourceFiles.CBEC_Website_Content.resWebsitePoliciesMenu</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-copyright">
                <div class="container">
                    <p class="copyright-text" title="© Content Owned, Updated &amp; Maintained by O/o Pr. CCA , Central Board of Indirect Taxes &amp; Customs, Department of Revenue, Ministry of Finance, Government of India">© Content Owned, Updated &amp; Maintained by </p>
                    <p class="copyright-text" title=" © Content Owned, Updated &amp; Maintained by O/o Pr. CCA , Central Board of Indirect Taxes &amp; Customs, Department of Revenue, Ministry of Finance, Government of India">O/o Pr. CCA , Central Board of Indirect Taxes &amp; Customs, Department of Revenue, Ministry of Finance, Government of India</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-------------------------------------------Middle Content FINISH---------------------------->
    <!-- javascript
        ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->


    <script src="~/Scripts/elmenu.js"></script>
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>*@
    <script src="~/Content/theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $(this).bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        function disableBackButton() {
            window.history.forward()
        }


        function noBack() {
            disableBackButton();
            window.onload = disableBackButton();
            window.onpageshow = function (evt) { if (evt.persisted) disableBackButton() }
            window.onunload = function () { void (0) }
        }

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        history.pushState(null, null, ' ');

        window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
            history.pushState(null, null, ' ');
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.pop').on('click', function () {
                $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
                $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
            });
        });

    </script>



    <script>
        //Code start for Menue activation
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (('Overview,OrganisationChart,OrganisationFunctions,DirectoryofOfficers').indexOf('@ViewBag.Title') >= 0) {
                $('#AboutUs').addClass('active');
                $('#' + '@ViewBag.Title').addClass('active');
            } else {
                $('#' + '@ViewBag.Title').addClass('active');
            }
        });
        //Code end for Menue activation

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var section;
        var factor = 0.8;

        function getFontSize(el) {
            var fs = $(el).css('font-size');
            if (!el.originalFontSize) el.originalFontSize = fs; //set dynamic property for later reset
            return parseFloat(fs);
        }

        function setFontSize(fact) {
            if (section == null)
                section = $('#content').find('*')
                .filter(
                  function () {
                      return $(this).clone()
                         .children()
                         .remove()
                         .end()
                         .text().trim().length > 0;
                  }); //filter -> exclude all elements without text

            section.each(function () {
                var newsize = fact ? getFontSize(this) * fact : this.originalFontSize;
                if (newsize) $(this).css('font-size', newsize);
            });
        }

        function resetFont() {
            setFontSize();
        }
        function increaseFont() {
            setFontSize(1 / factor);
        }
        function decreaseFont() {
            setFontSize(factor);
        }




    </script>
</body>
<style>
    .page-wrap:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
    }

    #footer, .page-wrap:after {
        height: 103px;
    }
</style>

</html>
```

when I check on the w3 validation. Below error is coming:-
Stray end tag “head”.
From line 30, column 1 to line 30, column 7
Code Extract:
dif]-->↩ ↩↩↩↩
Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.
From line 32, column 1 to line 32, column 19
Code Extract:
↩↩↩

How this will resolve. I am not able to understand. You can also check by
https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea . Same error will show.

Comment: Your problem is line 15

Comment: You have the `@*` characters in your `<head>` section outside `<title>`, `<style>` or `<script>` elements. It's interpreted as a simple text to output, which is not allowed in the `<head>`, so the `<head>` is implicitly closed and the `<body>` is implicitly open just before it, the rest of the elements supposed to be in the `<head>` end up being in `<body>`, and the closing `</head>` tag also appears in the `<body>` where it's meaningless.